# Opening file path not working in python

Tags: python, file

I am writing a database program and personica is my test subject (I would usually have a variable in the place of the file path, but for test and demo purposes I just have a string.). There is a text file at this exact location on my computer (I have changed my username on here, by the way because I am paranoid.), but it says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Project 
Documentation\InteractiveExecutable.py", line 46, in <module>
ReadPerson = open("C:/Users/Admin/Documents/Project 
Documentation/personica.txt", 'r')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
'C:/Users/Admin/Documents/Project Documentation/personica.txt'
```

This is the line of code:

```
ReadPerson = open("C:/Users/Admin/Documents/Project Documentation/personica.txt", 'r')
```

I am certain that it is there and when I copy that address into Windows Explorer, it takes me right to the text file.

Anyone know why this is not working?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using backslashes ``\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\``?

Comment: OTOH, since your text file is in the same directory as your script, `open('personica.txt')` does the trick.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye Windows typically accepts either.

Comment: Start using `pathlib` and all the worries of this life will magically melt away.

Comment: @RickTeachey `pathlib` magically corrects typos?

Comment: @Stefan used effectively, it would likely have prevented the typo in the first place.

Comment: Are you sure there are no non-English symbols in file's name or `Project Documentation`? What happens if you try opening a completely different file in a different place? What if you rename the file you already have? What if you move it to a different directory (e.g. one level up)?

Comment: How do I use pathlib?

Comment: @Fwinter1 I composed an answer to get you started on it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The new-ish [`pathlib` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) (available in Python >= 3.4) is great for working with path-like objects (both Windows and for other OSes).

### [It's Paths - Paths all the way down](https://xkcd.com/1416/)

To simplify: you can build up any path (directory and file path objects are treated exactly the same) as an object, which can be an *absolute path object* or a *relative path object*. You can use raw strings to make complex paths (i.e., `r'string'`) and `pathlib` will be very forgiving. However, note that there are better ways to build up paths than raw strings (see further down).

Here are examples:

```
from pathlib import Path

Path(r'c:\temp\foo.bar') # absolute path
Path(r'c:/temp/foo.bar') # same absolute path
Path('foo.bar') # different path, RELATIVE to current directory
Path('foo.bar').resolve() # resolve converts to absolute path
Path('foo.bar').exists() # check to see if path exists
```

Note that if you're on Windows `pathlib` forgives you for using the "wrong slash" in the second example. See discussion at the end about why you should probably *always* use the forward slash.

Simple displaying of some useful paths- such as the current working directory and the user home- works like this:

```
# Current directory (relative):
cwd = Path() # or Path('.')
print(cwd)

# Current directory (absolute):
cwd = Path.cwd()
print(cwd)

# User home directory:
home = Path.home()
print(home)

# Something inside the current directory
file_path = Path('some_file.txt') # relative path; or 
file_path = Path()/'some_file.txt' # also relative path
file_path = Path().resolve()/Path('some_file.txt') # absolute path
print(file_path)
```

To navigate down the file tree, you can do things like this. Note that the first object, `home`, is a `Path` and the rest are just strings:

```
some_person = home/'Documents'/'Project Documentation'/'personica.txt' # or
some_person = home.join('Documents','Project Documentation','personica.txt')
```

To read a file located at a path, you can use its `open` method rather than the `open` function:

```
with some_person.open() as f:
    dostuff(f)
```

But you can also just grab the text directly!

```
contents = some_person.read_text()
content_lines = contents.split('\n')
```

...and WRITE text directly!

```
data = '\n'.join(content_lines)
some_person.write_text(data) # overwrites existing file
```

Check to see if it is a file or a directory (and exists) this way:

```
some_person.is_dir()
some_person.is_file()
```

Make a new, empty file without opening it like this (silently replaces any existing file):

```
some_person.touch()
```

To make the file *only if it doesn't exist*, use `exist_ok=False`:

```
try:
    some_person.touch(exist_ok=False)
except FileExistsError:
    # file exists
```

Make a new directory (under the current directory, `Path()`) like this:

```
Path().mkdir('new/dir') # get errors if Path()/`new` doesn't exist
Path().mkdir('new/dir', parents=True) # will make Path()/`new` if it doesn't exist
Path().mkdir('new/dir', exist_ok=True) # errors ignored if `dir` already exists
```

Get the file extension or filename of a path this way:

```
some_person.suffix # empty string if no extension
some_person.stem # note: works on directories too
```

Use `name` for the entire last part of the path (stem and extension if they are there):

```
some_person.name # note: works on directories too
```

Rename a file using the `with_name` method (which returns the same path object but with a new filename):

```
new_person = some_person.with_name('personica_new.txt')
```

You can iterate through all the "stuff' in a directory like so using `iterdir`:

```
all_the_things = list(Path().iterdir()) # returns a list of Path objects
```

### Sidebar: backslashes (`\`)

Be careful when using backslashes in a path string, especially *ending* a path with a backslash. As with **any** string, Python will read that *terminating backslash* as an escape character *even in raw input mode*. Observe:

```
>>> r'\'
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    r'\'
       ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

So this will give a pretty cryptic error message if you are not aware of this issue:

```
>>> Path(r'C:\')
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    Path(r'\')
             ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

The reason for this error is that `\'` is assumed to be a single quotation *in the string*. This works fine: `'\''` (the second single quotation ends the string).

If you insist on using backslashes, be sure to use raw input mode or you will run into problems. For example, the `'\t'` character represents a tab. So when you do this (without raw input):

```
>>> Path('C:\temp')
```

You are putting a tab character into your path. This is perfectly legal and Python won't complain until you do something that causes Windows to try turning it into a real Windows path:

```
>>> Path('C:\temp').resolve()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'C:\temp'
```

This is also a very cryptic error if you do not know what is going on! Best to avoid the backslash characters altogether when messing about with paths.

### Preventing Your Problem

Your problem occurred when you created your file and erroneously added a double extension. To prevent this issue using `pathlib`, use the `touch` method to make the file:

```
some_person = Path.home()/'Documents'/'Project Documentation'/'personica.txt'
some_person.touch()
```

Comment: "Your problem occurred when you created your file and erroneously added a double extension." How exactly was this determined?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel because they were on Windows and this happens all the time on Windows because it hides file extensions.

Answer (score 3):

On Windows, I like to use Python's raw string format for file paths:

```
path = r'C:/Users/Admin/Documents/Project Documentation/personica.txt'
```

Note the `r` at the beginning of the string. Also note that the forward slash can be important as well.

Then I can just do the regular Python `open()` command:

```
with open(path) as fobj:
    for line in fobj:
        print line
```

See the String Literals section in Python's lexical analysis document:

- https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals

Comment: Worth noting that naively using backslashes (as most Windows users will do) and raw strings can still be a recipe for pain, i.e., `r'C:\'`. The forward slash is important to mention.

Comment: True enough. I rarely have had problems in raw strings with backslashes. If I don't use the raw string though, then I've had some pretty weird issues.