# Python: How to fix path special char string issue "\v"

Tags: python-3.x, path

I am trying to set the target path:

```
Target_Path = "C:\Doc\lib\vLib\setting.text"
```

However, the `\v` part is not accepted in python.

I tried to use `\\\\` or `/\v/` to fix this, referring to the similar [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44464686/opening-file-path-not-working-in-python).

```
Target_Path = "C:\Doc\lib/\v/Lib\setting.text"
```

However, it doesn't seem to work for this case.

Comment: What doesn't work from the other question you have linked? I don't see you using pathlib or raw string literals.

Comment: @mkrieger1 hello. thanks for helping me. I made a mistake so i miss import part. I added whole code that i have. I think there is way to fix \v part in path. Not sure how to fix it ...